# Please how can i update a nested mongodb embedded document, I have a document structure like this

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
user: {
 _id: objectId("5f5fd12521a9b27e849d9b7b")
 profile:{
    _id: objectId("5f5fd12521a9b27e849d9b7b")
    firstName: "Vincent"
    photo:{
      _id: objectId("5f5fd12521a9b27e849d9b7b")
      thumbnail: "/pictures/image.png"
      original: "/pictures/original/image.png"
}
}

}
```

I want to update the photo field as an embedded schema under profile which is an embedded schema to user.

Answer (score 1):

With Mongoose driver we can easily update nested documents.

Lets say you have fectched the document with mongoose, like below.

let document = await model.find ({ _id : '5f5fd12521a9b27e849d9b7b'});

Now you can simply assign the new data just like an object.

document.profile.photo= {...somestate};
await document.save();

That's it.

Comment: Yeah... thanks so much was able to get it fixed using the solution